# Disable mouse acceleration on WINE/lutris

Tags: wine, mouse, games

My sensitivity on overwatch with lutris is a lot higher than my windows machine, both use 6 sensitivity in game. I have set the dpi of my mouse to 400 and disabled mouse acceleration with gnome tweaks. My csgo has exactly the same sensitivity as my windows client so I know its possible. How do I get overwatch running on WINE to have the same sensitivity as native windows? Why does the game have mouse acceleration if I disabled it in ubuntu?

Thanks
Binary

Comment: "disable mouse acceleration in gnome". Thank you for that!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is most likely Wine as you seem to have already suspected. There's a MouseWarpOverride setting that can change how it handles the input from a mouse and often helps with issues like this. Winetricks can be used to change this (I believe it would be something like winetricks mwo=enable or mwo=disable or mwo=force), or there's some good Ubuntu-based directions [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1603263) that can tell you how to make a .reg file and use it to change this setting, including for a single app or globally (and Winetricks only does so globally it seems). Excerpt below:

> I would do the mouse warp override as:
>
> `REGEDIT4 [\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\AppDefaults\executable name\DirectInput] "MouseWarpOverride"="force"`
>
> Where .exe is the main executable of the program (e.g. Bioshock.exe - note: not the full path) that you to want to have mouse warping. I did a global mouse warping (to fix the problem of not being able to turn 360 degrees in Bioshock) however this ended up breaking other games...
>
> Global mouse warping is the key ( at your own risk ):
>
> `REGEDIT4 [\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\DirectInput] "MouseWarpOverride"="force"`
>
> There are 3 values for the value:
>   enable : (default) warp pointer when mouse exclusively acquired
>   disable : never warp the mouse pointer
>   force : always warp the mouse pointer
>
> Symptoms of an application not liking the "force"ed mouse warping include the mouse pointer bouncing around erratically in the middle of the screen and 'elastically' returning immediately to the middle of the screen...
>
> @OP but... I can't find it in my wine regedit, what should I do?
>
> @OP I can see AppDefaults or DirectInput in "\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine"
>
> @Bob Sorry my bad...
>
> You want to select one of the two options I gave you (an application specific override or a global override).
>
> Go into your home folder (in Nautilus).Create a blank document. Call this something like WINE_mouse_override.reg.Copy the information from one of the code windows in my post (beginning REGEDIT4).Paste this information into your newly created blank document - currently open in Gedit(I presume).Remember to insert in the executable name of your application (if using an application specific override)Open a terminal window (Gnome Menu - Accessories - Terminal).type or copy/paste into the terminal window:
>
> `cd ~ wine regedit WINE_mouse_override.reg`
>
> Then check in your WINE registry editor that the new key has been created...
>
> Bob