# Fusion 360 in WINE 5.5, mouse issue (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: wine, mouse

I installed Fusion 360 in Ubuntu 18.04 on WINE 5.5, pretty following this script.

https://gist.github.com/probonopd/0fab254aa0b6fc371d8db641822bd530#gistcomment-3228708

except for a few downloads from github that changed their naming, it works almost perfect for me.

I'm having an issue with the mouse though. It's hard to explain:

It seams the pointer captured by Wine is a few samples behind the actual pointer. Like there are some mouse inputs saved in a buffer and are played to the application sifted by a few time slices, producing a predictable (but super uncomfortable) lag.

Example 1:

1. I move the mouse from left to right
2. I try to pan the model to the right
3. It first moves a bit to the left and then starts moving to the right.

Example 2:

1. I scroll down a few times
2. I scroll up
3. The application first reacts scrolling one time down
4. Then scrolls the remaining times up

I'm sorry if it's not clear, but as I said, it's hard to explain.

I'm not sure if its the same issue, but I tried this solution and did't worked out: [Disable mouse acceleration on WINE/lutris](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071111/disable-mouse-acceleration-on-wine-lutris)

Did anyone came across this issue or know if there's a fix for it?

Thanks in advance!